# CSS codes hinder working with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have four divs with different classes and this is hindering to work with PHP. How ca I solve it?

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row st_sf_port_container st_sf_wall">
    <div class="st_sf_x1">

    </div>
    <div class="st_sf_x2">

    </div>
    <div class="st_sf_x2">

    </div>
    <div class="st_sf_x1">

    </div>
</div>
```

I should do like this:

```
$data = ["something1", "something2", "something3", "something4"];
<div class="row st_sf_port_container st_sf_wall">
       <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) { ?>
        <div class="st_sf_x1"><!-- here, how could I make like code above -->
            <?php echo $data[$i]; ?>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: you want to make divs via loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop over the array and find out substring using substr() function like:

```
<?php
$data = array("something1", "something2", "something3", "something4");
?>
<div class="row st_sf_port_container st_sf_wall">
<?php
foreach ($data as $elem) {
$iterator = strlen($elem) > 9 ? substr($elem, 9, 1) : 0;
?>
<div class="st_sf_x<?php echo $iterator;?>"><!-- here, how could I make like code above -->
<?php echo $data[$i]; ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Note his div classes go 1 2 2 1... not 1 2 3 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here `class="st_sf_x<?php echo $i ?>"` will change the name of the class with each iteration like st_sf_x1, st_sf_x2 etc. so that you can give different css to each class as you prefer.

```
 $data = ["something1", "something2", "something3", "something4"];
    <div class="row st_sf_port_container st_sf_wall">
           <?php for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) { ?>
            <div class="st_sf_x<?php echo $i ?>">
                <?php echo $data[$i]; ?>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and would accomodate any class combination or order:

```
$data = [ 
    ["content" => "something1", "class" => "st_sf_x1"],
    ["content" => "something2", "class" => "st_sf_x2"],
    ["content" => "something3", "class" => "st_sf_x2"],
    ["content" => "something4", "class" => "st_sf_x1"]
];
<div class="row st_sf_port_container st_sf_wall">
   <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) { ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $data[$i]["class"]; ?>">
        <?php echo $data[$i]["content"]; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: But, in $data array I can not give "class" => "value" for every element. Because, I have a lot of groups like this array.

Comment: @AlisherNasrullayev - does the `class` always repeat 1221, 1221... ?

Comment: Yeah. They are in one group and there are many groups like those.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data  = ["something1", "something2", "something3", "something4"];
$class = ['st_sf_x1'  , 'st_sf_x2'  , 'st_sf_x2'  , 'st_sf_x1'];
?>
<div class="row st_sf_port_container st_sf_wall">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) { ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $class[$i] ?>">
            <?php echo $data[$i]; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```